# Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`ShoppingCart`). Can someone tell me where this error is?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a shopping cart but I keep getting this error when I try to add the item to the cart.

react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`ShoppingCart`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `ShoppingCart`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
at ShoppingCart (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:911:5)
at App (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:105:94)

I think the issue may be in my ProductCards component with the onClick function but I have no idea. Please help!

```js
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

   //Components
   import FilterableTable from './components/FilterableTable'
   import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar'
   import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
   import ShoppingCart from './components/ShoppingCart'


   function App() {


    //Snowboard Array
   const SnowboardArray = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Thunder Bolt",
        availability: "in stock",
        shape: "directional",
        Level: "Expert",
        terrain: '',
        size: "156",
        price: "500",
        rating: '3',
        image: thunderBolt,
      },
  // Removed array to make code smaller
  ]
  
    //State 
    const [filteredSearch, setFilteredSearch] = useState(''); 
    
    //State for shopping cart
    
    //Cart visibility
    const [cartsVisibility, setCartsVisibility] = useState(false)
    //Products in cart
    const [productsInCart, setProductsInCart] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shopping-cart")) || []);

    // Use effect
    useEffect(()=> {
      localStorage.setItem("shopping-cart", JSON.stringify(productsInCart))
    }, [productsInCart])

    //Functions

    //Add to cart
    function addProductToCart(item) {
      const newItem = {...item, count: 1} // creating a new object. Grabbing item and all of its properties with spread operator. Adding count prop.
      setProductsInCart([...productsInCart, newItem ]); //Adding all elements currently in state plus the new item with its new count prop.
    }

    // Update quanitity
    function onQuantityChange(itemId, count) { // Takes in product ID and count props from item that's being changed
      setProductsInCart((currentState) => { // updating state with setter function and referring to current state (values currently in state)
        const productIndex = currentState.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId); // Grabbing current state and chaining on the findIndex method that iterates
        // the array and looks for the index of the item in the current state with the ID that matches the ID from the item that's being queried.

        // An IF check is ran to check if the state value 'productsInCart' is not equal to -1. If this is true, the code is executed.
        if (productsInCart !== -1) {  // Checks if there's items in the cart
          currentState[productIndex].count = count; // searches the current state array for the index that matches. Accesses the count property and sets it to 'count
          // *currentState[productIndex = integer]*
        }
        return [...currentState];
      })
    }

    // Remove Item
    function onProductRemove(item) { // When the button is pressed, the item will be passed to the function
      setProductsInCart((currentState) => { // Using state setter function to update state. Referring to currentState to access the current state.
        const productsIndex = currentState.findIndex((product) => product.id === item.id); 
      // Accessing current state and calling the find index method to search for the index of the product who's product ID matches the ID of the item being queried.
      // ProductsIndex now holds the index of the item that matches the one being queried.

      // If the item's index is valid (currently in the array), it is removed from the array using the splice method.
        if (productsIndex !== -1) {
          currentState.splice(productsIndex, 1);
        }
        // Otherwise, the original current state is returned
        return [...currentState];
      })
    }





     return (
       <>
         <Navbar setCartsVisibility={setCartsVisibility} productsInCart={productsInCart}/>
         <SearchBar arr={SnowboardArray}/>
         <FilterableTable arr={SnowboardArray} setFilteredSearch={setFilteredSearch} setProductsInCart={setProductsInCart} addProductToCart={addProductToCart}/>
         <ShoppingCart cartsVisibility={cartsVisibility} productsInCart={productsInCart} onQuantityChange={onQuantityChange} onProductRemove={onProductRemove} onClose={() => setCartsVisibility(false)
                }/>
       </>
     )
   }

   export default App
```

```js
import React from 'react'

//Css
import '../css/ShoppingCart.scss'

//Icons 
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

function ShoppingCart({
    cartsVisibility, //Visibility of shopping cart
    productsInCart, //Products in shopping cart
    onProductRemove, //On products remove
    onClose, //When shopping cart is closed
    onQuantityChange, //Change quantity of product
}) {
  

  return (
    <div className="modal" style={{display: cartsVisibility ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
        <div className="shoppingCart">
        <div className="header">
            <h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
            {/* Close btn */}
            <button className='btn close-btn' onClick={onClose}>
                <CloseIcon />
            </button>
        </div>
        {/* Shopping Cart products */}
        <div className="cart-products">
            {productsInCart.length === 0 && ( <span className='empty-text'>Your cart is currently empty.</span>)}
            {productsInCart.map((product) => (
                
                <div className='cart-product' key={product.id}>
                    <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                    <div className="product-info">
                        <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                        <span className='product-price'>€{product.price * product.count}</span>
                    </div>
                    <select className='count' value={product.count} onChange={(event) => onQuantityChange(product.id, event.target.value)}>
                        {[...Array(10).keys()].map(number => {
                            const num = number + 1;
                            return <option value={{num}} key={num}>{num}</option>
                            // return <option value={num} key={num}>{num}</option>

                        })}
                    </select>
                    <button className='btn remove-btn' onClick={onProductRemove(product)}><DeleteIcon /></button>
                </div>
            ))}
            {productsInCart.length > 0 && <button className='btn checkout-btn'>Proceed to checkout.</button>}
        </div>
        </div>
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default ShoppingCart
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'

//Components 
import TypeSelector from './TypeSelector'
import ProductCards from './ProductCards'

function FilterableTable({arr, setProductsInCart, addProductToCart}) {

   // State to store the all items / full product array
 const [allObjects, setAllobjects] = useState([]);

 // State to store the filtered array 'type'
 const [filteredObjects, setFilteredObjects] = useState();

 // Use effect to put the full product array inside the all objects state variable on mount
 useEffect(() => {
  setAllobjects(arr);
 }, []);

 // Function to filter the main array with the selected filter value stored in the state
 // Original function that wasn't working.
 //  function getFilteredList() {
 //   if (!filteredObjects) {
 //     return allObjects;  
 //   } 
 //     if (filteredObjects === 'directional' || 'directional-twin' || 'twin' ) {
 //       return allObjects.filter((object) => object.shape === filteredObjects)

 //     } else if (filteredObjects === '154' || '156' || '157' ) {
 //       return allObjects.filter((object) => object.size === filteredObjects)
 //     }
 //  }

 function getFilteredList() {
    if (!filteredObjects) {
      return allObjects;  
    } 
    const allowedSizes = ['154', '156', '157'];
    if (allowedSizes.includes(filteredObjects)) {
      return allObjects.filter((object) => object.size === filteredObjects);
    } else {
      return allObjects.filter((object) => object.shape === filteredObjects);
    }
  }

    // Use memo hook is used to prevent multiple calls. Only calls function when state changes
    // Everything is now stored in FilteredList variable
    let filteredList = useMemo(getFilteredList, [allObjects, filteredObjects]);



  return (

    <>

        {/* Dropdown selector */}
          <TypeSelector setFilteredObjects={setFilteredObjects}/>

        {/* Product cards */}
        <div className="card-container" style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: '1rem'}}>
        {filteredList.map((object, index) => (
          <ProductCards {...object} key={index} setProductsInCart={setProductsInCart} addProductToCart={addProductToCart} />
        ))}
        </div>
    </>

  )
}

export default FilterableTable
```

```js
import React from 'react'

//Styles
import '../css/ProductCards.scss';

//Components
import Ratings from '../components/Ratings';

function ProductCards ({addProductToCart, ...object}) { 


  return (

    <div className="card">
      <img src={object.image} alt='Image' />
      <button onClick={() => addProductToCart(object)}>Add to cart</button>
      <h3>{object.name}</h3>
      <p>Directional freeride snowboard</p>
      {/* <span>reviews</span> */}
      <span>€{object.price}</span>
      <Ratings arr={object} />
      {/* <p>{object.id}</p> */}
      <p>{object.types}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductCards
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are supplying the `onProductRemove` directly to the onClick callback. This would cause the function to be executed while rendering the component as the return value of the `onProductRemove` is set to the callback.

In order to fix this issue you need to update the callback to be:

```
<button className='btn remove-btn' onClick={ ()=> onProductRemove(product)}><DeleteIcon /></button>
```

By adding an arrow function before it, we prevent the `onProductRemove` function from being called until the click event.

Comment: Im now getting this error

Comment: bundle.js:17177 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `2`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at ShoppingCart (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:910:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:105:94)

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: In react, every time you use the map operator on a list inside of the rendering function you need to specify a unique key to elements. This helps react optimize the rendering of the components. Check this link for further details: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html